# Selenium attempts connection to localhost while browsing to external URL

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium v2.30.0 and Firefox 19.0. When I execute the below code:

```
public class First_Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:

> "Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms"

I've searched everywhere for an answer with no success. All help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the alternate `driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some problem while waiting for the response

try this code instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    query.sendKeys("Cheers!");

    // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

        // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
        if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
          break;
        }
    }

    // And now list the suggestions
    List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

    for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
        System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Selenium to v2.31. Firefox 19 is not supported in anything lower.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list